# Is collision in ideal gas because of physical collision or due to repulsion force

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, collision, ideal-gas

Is collision in [ideal gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) because of physical collision or due to repulsion force when they approach close by?

Comment: One of the properties of an ideal gas is that the molecules do not collide with one another.

Comment: You may think this is a dumb question, but at the atomic level, what do you mean by a "physical collision"?

Comment: I meant actually hitting each other..does that no happen at atomic level.?

Comment: Nothing ever touches anything else in the intuitive way we think of; there's always a gap between any two things -- microscopic or macroscopic -- due to repulsive forces. That said, gasses can be modeled by "hard spheres" (search wikipedia) which collide in the way we immagine. However, that's just a model -- not reality.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal gas should consist of pointlike particles that are non-interacting, except if they collide, in which case they should do so elastically, without losing kinetic energy.

I do not think there is any distinction here between a collision and a repulsive force. Any short-range repulsive force between particles (short-range compared with the average inter-particle separation) will provide for something that approximates to an ideal gas. In practice, what we call a collision is a repulsive force acting at short range.

Answer (score 0):

In one way, we can assume that particles repulsing when they "approach close by" is similar to particles with larger sizes colliding.  It means that particles cannot approach arbitrarily close.  This may not be exactly what you are distinguishing with "physical collision", but it has consequences for ideal gases.

The greater the distance of this interaction, the more the gas diverges from ideal.  The [Van der Waals equation of state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) uses this distance as a parameter in its correction to the ideal gas equations.  As the interaction distance increases, the number of particles that can occupy a given volume decreases.  This causes the pressure to scale non-linearly with the number of particles.

All gases are made of particles that interact at non-zero distances, so there are no gases that behave in an ideal manner under all conditions.